# Replace perror(argv[0]) with stderr

Tags: c, shell, unix, system-calls

Is there a way I can replace perror(argv[0]) in a code with stderr instead, while retaining the functionality? What exactly is the difference between the two? Can they be used interchangeably as and when we wish to?

Comment: `perror()` writes to standard error...

Comment: They are not interchangeable.  `perror` writes a string of yours, plus a string derived from `errno`, to `stderr`.  You can do the same thing, using `strerror`.

Comment: `perror` is a function which prints its argument plus information a bout the error to `stderr`. `stderr` is just a file descriptor associated with an error stream and which can be used in other output operations that use file descriptors. So, the question about replacing perror with stderr makes no sense. However, you can replace perror with other output functios.

Comment: Look at the [source code](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/perror.c) of `perror()`.